# Calculated Field Based on Corresponding Row Month

Tags: tableau-api

For a table:

```
 Month    Source  Num    Denom

May-2016    1      28      30
May-2016    2      10      17
Jun-2016    1      40      42
Jun-2016    2      15      23
```

I wanted to please know how to create a calculated field in two ways:

1) Return a C. Field=Num/Denom for only June-2016 explicitly (or any corresponding row month)

2) Return a C. Field=Num/Denom for the previous month in the Month column from the current month in time (Current month is July. So I want the division to be for fields corresponding to June 2016 in the Month column)

Expected Output(Calculating only for June 2016):

```
40+15/42+23 = 0.846 (If not drilled down to Source)
40/42=0.95 (If drilled down to Source For Source 1)
15/23=0.65 (If drilled down to Source For Source 2)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If I do a `SUM[Num]/SUM[Denom]`, it gives me the calculation for the sum of all months so I'm struggling to figure how to force Tableau to do it only for Jun-2016.

Comment: What is your expected output? Your calculated would work if you present the data at the `Month` grain, otherwise it will aggregated all months. You need to clarify what you are expecting as your output.

Comment: Updated for Output. I'm trying to do exactly that. Do the division based on the Month grain where I can either specify the Month I want Tableau to calculate for or do it for the month prior to the current month in time. (Eg: Calculate for June since current month is July)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can calculate a month's data *explicitly*:

```
SUM(IF [month] = 'Jun-2016' THEN [Num] END)
/
SUM(IF [month] = 'Jun-2016' THEN [Denom] END)
```

I'm not sure if your `[month]` field is a text field or an actual date field, but if it is a date field you can make this calculation more dynamic, like so:

```
SUM(IF DATEDIFF("month",[month],TODAY()) = 1 THEN [Num] END)
/
SUM(IF DATEDIFF("month",[month],TODAY()) = 1 THEN [Denom] END)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Just what the doctor ordered.